# Add Bootstrap styled radio button from ASP code behind

Tags: c#, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, radio-button

I need to generate a set of radio buttons on a web page dynamically.  In order to style them appropriately for Bootstrap they need to look like this:

```
<div class="col-sm-3">
    <div class="radio">
        <label>
            <input type="radio" name="radioButtonGroup" value="1" />
            Option 1
        </label>
    </div>
</div>
```

I'm currently generating the buttons from the code-behind like so:

```
RadioButton r = new RadioButton
{
    AutoPostBack = true,
    GroupName = "radioButtonGroup",
    Text = "Option 1"
};
r.Attributes.Add("Value", "1");
r.CheckedChanged += RadioButtonChanged;

HtmlGenericControl inner = new HtmlGenericControl("div");
inner.Attributes.Add("class", "radio");
inner.Controls.Add(r);

HtmlGenericControl outer = new HtmlGenericControl("div");
outer.Attributes.Add("class", "col-lg-3");
outer.Controls.Add(inner);

RadioButtonDiv.Controls.Add(outer);
```

And this gives me something *close* but no cigar:

```
<div class="col-sm-3">
    <div class="radio">
        <input id="ctl00_body_ctl02" type="radio" name="ctl00$body$radioButtonGroup" value="1" onclick="javascript: setTimeout('__doPostBack(\'ctl00$body$ctl02\',\'\')', 0)">
        <label for="ctl00_body_ctl02">Option 1</label>
    </div>
</div>
```

Ignoring all the ASP junk, the problem is that the label doesn't wrap around the input, and the formatting in Bootstrap ends up all ugly.

Does anyone know of a way to force ASP.Net to wrap the input in the label?  Or am I approaching this wrong somehow.

The only other option I see is to generate the radio buttons from Javascript using an AJAX query.  I actually started down that path before I realised I needed to perform server-side actions when the value changes.  So although I can create them client-side, and attach the server-side events, I lose the state on each post.  It's probably possible to do it that way, but it seems even more clunky.

---

**Update:** So I realised if I don't set the text on the radio button directly, I can wrap it in a label.  Still no go.  I can insert a `System.Web.UI.WebControls.Label`, but it generates a `<span>` in the HTML.
I can insert `new HtmlGenericControl("label");` and that generates a label correctly, but I can't add the control first and *then* text:

```
HtmlGenericControl radioLabel = new HtmlGenericControl("label");
radioLabel.Controls.Add(r);
radioLabel.InnerText = "Option1";
```

Generates `<label>Option1</label>` but no radio button.  Reversing the order of control and text like so:

```
HtmlGenericControl radioLabel = new HtmlGenericControl("label");
radioLabel.InnerText = "Option1";
radioLabel.Controls.Add(r);
```

Results in `<label>Option1<input ...></label>` and that doesn't render correctly (the radio button overlaps the text).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't find a way to do this.  I'll leave the question here as I think it's still a valid question

The way I worked around it was to generate the radio buttons client-side (javascript) and use an AJAX POST to trigger server-side actions (via WCF Data Services).

It doesn't feel right to mark this as the correct answer, since it's a work-around, and not strictly an answer for the question.  However [community wiki](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) says I should post and accept whatever solution I found:

> Eventually you'll resolve the problem or find a work-around (which may be, "This won't work, so here's what I did instead"). Please add an answer with this information and accept your own answer so that others with your same question can see the path you eventually followed.

That said I'm happy to update the "correct" answer if anyone has another way to do it.